# Incorrect syntax near '('. issue

Tags: sql

I create a stored procedure like this:

```
INSERT (keyMolde, nEficiencia, nCavidades, 
        mdFechaCarga,mdOrigenCarga, mdUsuarioCarga, bActivo)
        VALUES (Origen.keyMolde, Origen.nEficiencia, CASE WHEN  CAST(Origen.sCavidades AS INT) = Origen.sCavidades THEN Origen.sCavidades  
       ELSE CAST(Origen.sCavidades AS Numeric(12,0)) END, 
                Origen.mdFechaCarga, Origen.mdOrigenCarga, Origen.mdUsuarioCarga, Origen.bActivo);
```

When I try to run I get `Incorrect syntax near '('.` but I really dont find where I miss to close '(' , first i thin I forget into `VALUES`

```
 (Origen.keyMolde, Origen.nEficiencia, CASE WHEN  CAST(Origen.sCavidades AS INT) = Origen.sCavidades THEN Origen.sCavidades  
           ELSE CAST(Origen.sCavidades AS Numeric(12,0)) END
```

So I try to put another ')' as : `ELSE CAST(Origen.sCavidades AS Numeric(12,0))) END` but sql throw Incorrect syntax near ')', how should I suppose to end this sentence? can anyone helo me there?

Comment: Is `Origen` a table?  If so, then this should be an `INSERT INTO..SELECT FROM` not `INSERT INTO ..VALUES`.

Comment: You do not appear to have the same number of ( as you do ).

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Ollie said in comments, change your insert to use `INSERT INTO.. SELECT`:

```
INSERT INTO Table --Table you want to insert to
            (keyMolde, 
             nEficiencia, 
             nCavidades, 
             mdFechaCarga,
             mdOrigenCarga, 
             mdUsuarioCarga, 
             bActivo)
SELECT Origen.keyMolde, 
       Origen.nEficiencia, 
       CASE WHEN  CAST(Origen.sCavidades AS INT) = Origen.sCavidades 
            THEN Origen.sCavidades  
            ELSE CAST(Origen.sCavidades AS Numeric(12,0)) END, 
       Origen.mdFechaCarga, 
       Origen.mdOrigenCarga, 
       Origen.mdUsuarioCarga, 
       Origen.bActivo
FROM Origen
```